# jstl dropdown selected

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl

So I have a spring binded dropdown similar to shown below. My question I want to 
show ALL ID as the selected option whenever getAllID value is true. I know the selected 
value is based on the value provided by spring bind element, in this case `studentID` but is there anyway I can override that anytime my boolean condition is true?

```
<spring:bind path="student.studentID">      
   <select name="${status.expression}" value="${status.value}">
       <option />
    <option value="001">1</option>
    <option value="002">2</option>
    <option value="003">3</option>
    <option value="ALLID"
        <c:if test='${student.getAllID eq true}'> Selected </c:if>>ALL ID
    </option>

     </select>
</spring:bind>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the fix. Added c:if to Select tag:

```
<c:if test='${student.getAllID ne true}'>
            value="${status.value}" 
</c:if>
```